# How to convert old middleware func to new middleware func

Tags: go, middleware, gorilla, martini

I have this existing library call:

```
func Policy(quota *Quota, options ...*Options) func(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    o := newOptions(options)
    if o.Disabled {
        return func(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {}
    }
   /// ...
}
```

we used to use Martini but are updating to Mux since Martini is no longer maintained. The old Martini router called it like so:

```
m := &martini.ClassicMartini{bm, r}

m.Use(throttle.Policy(&throttle.Quota{
    Limit:  10000,
    Within: 24 * time.Hour,
}))
```

but I need to update it for mux middleware like so:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.Use(func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fun := throttle.Policy(&throttle.Quota{
            Limit:  10000,
            Within: 24 * time.Hour,
        })
        fun(w,r)
        h.ServeHTTP(w,r);
    })
});
```

the above "seems to be correct" but I really am not sure. It would be nice to be able to check the return value of `fun()` to see if I should continue calling the remaining middleware. This is a flaw I am not sure how to solve with golang.

Comment: *"It would be nice to be able to check the return value of fun() to see if I should continue calling the remaining middleware."* `fun`'s type (the return type of the `Policy` function) is defined as having *no* return arguments, therefore there is nothing to check. If `Policy` is your function and not a 3rd party one, then you can change the return type to a function type that does return something, say a boolean, then, you could, in the middleware check for the value returned by the call to `fun` and proceed accordingly. Something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/eWUu3mF11pI

Comment: ... note that in the example above the initialization of `fun` was moved from the handler's body to the handler's surrounding closure. I've moved it there only because I assume that's where it should be. However, whether or not it *actually* should be there depends on how the policy is implemented, which is something you must know and is therefore for you to decide, but keep in mind that, again depending on the implementation, based on where it's initialized your middleware may do what you want, or it may be completely useless.

Comment: i am confused I am just looking for away to refactor this

Comment: Is there something specific you're confused with that I could maybe try to explain better?

Comment: utlimately it can't really be refactored very easily, the library itself has to be altered